# is there way to invalidate a token with JWT or add it to blacklist

Tags: node.js, express, security, authentication, jwt

jwt blacklist a valide token

For my API i'm using this package jwt-node for authentication

after sending a POST req to /users with a valid form data it will create a userr

```
/users [POST]
```

after that to login he will send us  POST req to /users/login with email and password and he will get a token valid token for 1 day

```
/users/login [POST]
```

now if the user would like to delete his account he will send DELETE request to /users and i will delete his account

```
/users [DELETE]
```

but the problem is the token will be valid for 1 day so even if his account is not available he has a valid token

is there way to invalidate a token with JWT or add it to blacklist